# Problem with multiplication of matrices following Glynn's formula for calculating the permanent

Tags: c++, math, matrix

I'm trying to implement in C++ the calculation of the matrix permanent following the [Glynn formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent#Balasubramanian%E2%80%93Bax%E2%80%93Franklin%E2%80%93Glynn_formula).

[image]

I try to explain briefly how this formula works. Suppose we have an `nxn` matrix.

```
| a b c |
| d e f | 
| g h i |
```

To calculate the permanent with the Glynn formula I should try to execute "a kind" of matrix product with a matrix that is a table of truths of length `2^n` with `n/2` rows and `n` columns.

Something like this. Suppose a matrix with `n = 3`.

```
| a b c | |+ + +|
| d e f | |+ - +|
| g h i | |+ + -|
          |+ - -|
```

development of the formula. I have to get:

```
∆(a + b + c)(d + e + f)(g + h + i)
```

where:

`∆` è equal to the product of the first of the sign matrix (therefore `+ * + * + = +`). The positive sign of `a, b` and `c` I got it by multiplying the first column of the matrix of letters by the sign of the first row of the sign matrix.

The order is then: multiply the first column of matrix A for the first row of the matrix of signs, multiply the second column of matrix A for the first row of the matrix of signs and then multiply the last column of matrix A for the first line of the matrix of the signs.

This is the first step. The second will be to multiply the first column of matrix A for the second row of the matrix of signs, multiply the second column of matrix A for the second row of the matrix of signs and then multiply the third column of matrix A for the second row of matrix signs and so on..

The end result is this:

```
= + (a + b + c)(d + e + f)(g + h + i) 
  - (a - b + c)(d - e + f)(g - h + i) 
  - (a + b - c)(d + e - f)(g + h - i)
  + (a - b - c)(d - e - f)(g - h - i)
```

I am trying to implement this algorithm in C. I have correctly created a random matrix `nxn` and the matrix of the signs I have encoded it in this way to perform the multiplications in a simple way (`+ = 1` and `- = -1`).
So the product I have to do is:

```
| a b c | |1  1  1|
| d e f | |1 -1  1|
| g h i | |1  1 -1|
          |1 -1 -1|
```

The function that I tried to create to run those products and those sums is:

```
double permanent(double input_matrix[n][n], int sign_matrix[][n]){

int rows =  pow (2, n) ;
int partial_result = 0;
int result = 1;

for(int r = 0; r < n; r++)
{
   for(int c = 0; c < n; c++)
   {
      partial = partial + input_matrix[c][r] * sign_matrix[r][c];
      //cout << parziale <<  endl;
   }

   cout << partial << endl;
   partial_result = partial_result * parziale;
   partial = 0;

}
```

The problem is that when I execute `partial = partial + input_matrix [c][r] * sign_matrix [r][c];` I can not "hold the line of the matrix of signs steady, with the cause that the product is wrong because I multiply the first column of matrix A for the first row of the sign matrix (right). second row of the sign matrix (wrong! I should also multiply the second column for the first row of the sign matrix as in the written formula).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you have your matrix product the wrong way round. It should be S*A where S is the sign matrix

Comment: You are right. I try to change and see if it comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you really need to check twice your understanding of the equation. Remember that each summation or multiplication is a for loop. So, by using the notation in the [original paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82475558.pdf), you get this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using mat = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;

double permanent(const mat& input_matrix, const mat& sign_matrix)
{
    int m = input_matrix.size();
    assert(m > 2);
    assert(input_matrix[0].size() == m);
    assert(sign_matrix.size() == m);
    int cols = sign_matrix[0].size();
    assert(cols == 1 << (m - 1));

    double result = 0;
    for (int t = 0; t < cols; ++t) {
        double delta = 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < m; ++k) {
            delta *= sign_matrix[k][t];
        }
        double p = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            double s = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                s += sign_matrix[i][t] * input_matrix[i][j];
            }
            p *= s;
        }
        result += delta * p;
    }
    return result / cols;
}

int main()
{
    mat A = { 
        { 1, 4, 7, }, 
        { 2, 5, 8, }, 
        { 3, 6, 9, },
    };
    mat sign_mat = {
        { 1,  1,  1,  1, },
        { 1, -1,  1, -1, },
        { 1,  1, -1, -1, },
    };
    auto perA = permanent(A, sign_mat);
}
```